# How reliable is using contenteditable on a div for a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I believe the title is pretty self-explanatory but still, maybe, I should ask in detail. I'm building a WYSIWYG editor and I'm really at the beginning of it. So, I realized that maybe knowing the pros and cons would enlighten me. Basically, my question is, since I want an editor that would work at least with 90% in all major browsers, how further I can go using contenteditable within a div and what are the cons and pros of using contenteditable when compared with designMode and iframe? Also, while researching I've found [this editor](http://ajaxorg.github.com/ace/build/editor.html). I believe it is not using any of these attributes and it's moving the location of textarea. Is this a better approach? Well, I know that there are lots of factors that influence the answer on the last question, but as I mentioned, the most important thing I look up in the editor is that it can be used by the 90% of the users. NB: I do not want to use any third party libraries.

Comment: The editor you mentioned is not a WYSIWYG editor, just a plain text editor with highlighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most uses, my preference is still for an iframe with `designMode` on most browsers and a contenteditable `<body>` element in IE, which makes it easier to work with. The reasons:

- Having the editable content in an iframe effectively sandboxes it and allows you to drop the editor into any page with confidence that the page's CSS and DOM events cannot affect the editable content
- `designMode` is more reliable in Firefox. I've seen several bugs with `contenteditable` that don't exist with `designMode`, which is probably because contenteditable was added to Firefox relatively recently whereas designMode has existed since around 2003.

As to ACE, its textarea approach is clever and has many advantages but I suspect the approach is limited to monospaced fonts. Also, [CodeMirror 2 uses a related approach](http://codemirror.net/internals.html) but is similarly limited to monospaced fonts.

Comment: thanks Tim. The only thing that sticks me using contentEditable is that I dont like using iframe. Probably because of previous readings I've done years ago on this tag. Or maybe a misunderstanding. I believe using div is much more valid than iframe. That's only a belief tho, I didnt make a research :) As for FF, I know that contenteditable is not supported in firefox 2 but after having done a little research I've found that ff2 has not even the share of 1% among the major browsers. So, do you believe that a good WYSIWYG editor (at least 90% of users targeted) is possible using contentEditable?

Comment: @Shaokan: Yes, I think contenteditable is usable as it is. There's nothing invalid about an iframe though, and at least two of the major WYSIWYG editors (TinyMCE and CKEditor) use them.

Comment: I would counter your first argument; that the CSS of the page is not going to affect what you are editing. This is actually my biggest problem with CKEditor: people cannot see what they are doing because the editor CSS is different from the real page CSS, in other words, that editor is NOT WYSIWYG.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Fair point, but it depends on context. If the editor is in a page other than the one being edited (for example, within some kind of page editing form within a content management system), you wouldn't want the editable area to inherit its CSS from the current page. CKEditor 4 has an inline mode now, by the way: http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline

Answer (score 4):

`contentEditable` does not work with floats in IE:

```
<p>
  <img style="float:left" src="foo">
  <p contentEditable="true">very long text here ...
    ... this text won't flow round the image</p>
</p>
```

This is because `contentEditable` triggers the infamous [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).
Other than that, everything works pretty well.

Comment: hmm I did not know that, thanks a lot! Yo prewarned me for a possible problem :)

Answer (score 2):

> The `designMode` and `contentEditable` attributes, and the APIs that drive rich text editors, are implemented in all major browsers, including Firefox, Opera, Safari, Google Chrome, and of course Internet Explorer.

http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable

Mark Finkle wrote a nice [high-level summary of designMode](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2007/02/xul-clippings-midas-rich-text-editor/), and later added [a post about contentEditable](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2007/07/firefox-3-contentEditable/).