# Can you run execcommand on an element besides document?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

Can you do `execcommand` on an element besides document?

I'm wondering if you can write code like this:

```
contentDiv.execCommand()
```

instead of:

```
document.execCommand()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `execCommand()` is limited to `HTMLDocument` nodes (see [work-in-progress HTML Editing spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#execcommand%28%29)), except for IE, in which their proprietary `TextRange` and `ControlRange` objects [also support `execCommand()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: hi Tim, thanks, that's good to know. Hmm, this maybe be a reason to have the contenteditable element be an iframe and not a div such that someone couldn't screw up your webpage. The damage would be restricted to an iframe. I'm trying to understand why most WYSIWYG editors use iframes instead of just editing a `<div>` directly. It seems that it might have most to do with having a hidden `<textarea>` element that you could submit in a `<form>`. What do you think?

Comment: That and the fact that contenteditable hasn't been supported in key browsers (iOS 1-4) earlier on?

Comment: @timpeterson: `designMode` isn't supported in iOS < 5 either, so using an iframe wouldn't help there. I know I've written about this at least once before on SO; the best I could dig out is http://stackoverflow.com/a/5686070/96100